# [ODBC Firebird Driver][Firebird]attempted update during read-only transaction

Tags: c#, .net, odbc, firebird

I am getting above error during an insert query firebird, 
Following is snippet of my code, i use odbc connection to perform and insert command

**[ODBC Firebird Driver][Firebird]attempted update during read-only transaction**

```
 using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection(string.Format("dsn={0};UID={1};PWD={2};", dsn, user, pwd)))
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    foreach (var track in tracking)
                    {
                        string insertSQL = string.Format("INSERT INTO SHIPPINGIMPORT (TRACKINGNUM, SHIPCARTONID) VALUES ('{0}','{1}')",track.TrackingNum, track.CartonId);
                        using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(insertSQL, cn))
                        {
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;  
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I am using odbc connection, the fault was actually in the odbc connection configuration. You simply need to **un-check** the read (default write)[image: Un-check read radio button]. 
Now it works like a charm. Hope this helps someone.